# PHP mail function interrupting jquery .post return data

Tags: jquery, php

I don't really understand what's going on here. I have a jquery script that sends form post data to a signup script, where upon an email is sent to the user signing up and the users Id is returned back to the calling jquery function where it is forwarded to yet another script for processing.

Problem: The script works great if I leave out the mail function, however, introducing it into the script blocks the variable from being returned to the calling jquery function. Any ideas what's going on? Here is the Jquery script:

```
<script>
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#purchaseForm").submit(function(event) {

    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;


/* stop form from submitting normally */
event.preventDefault(); 


    $.post("process_signup.php", $("#purchaseForm").serialize(),function(data){
                                                if(intRegex.test(data)){
                    if(data!=0){
                        alert(data);
                    document.getElementById("bag_contents_hidden").value=data;  
                    $.post("process_order.php", $("#bag_contents").serialize(), function(data2){
                    if(data2){
                    window.location.replace("?process=100&success=1");  
                    }else{
                    window.location.replace("?process=100&fail=1"); 
                    }
                });

            }
        }

else{       //Not Important, validation stuff       


}



        });

  });
```

//

```
PHP 
                      if($oid){
               if(mail($email,$title,$message,$headers,'O DeliveryMode=b')){

                    echo $oid;
                    unset($_POST['processorder_hidden']);
                    }else{
                    echo 0; 
                          }
                }
```

Comment: Please post the PHP.  Possibly the `mail()` call is causing some unexpected output that jQuery isn't prepared for.

Comment: Hi Michael, I will update the original code in a bit. Sorry about leaving out the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are expecting a data from the `post` request any errors generated by `mail` function is sure to create problems.

Here is a correct way to solve it

```
$status = @mail($to, $subject, $content); //suppress the error generated from being passed to the view

//instead handle it later
if($status) {
   //handle success
} else {
  //handle unsuccess
}
```

Comment: No, the solution isn't to prevent errors from being thrown and ignore them. It's to prevent them from being output to the screen.

Comment: @Michael, I think i didn't make myself clear. Handling part is for specific program flow, the `@` is enough to stop the output on the screen.

Comment: If OP decides to output on success or unsuccess then its up to him.

Comment: @Michael, in order to solve the underlying problem, he should handle the error correctly, checking the $status.

Comment: You are both right. I didn't know I could suppress errors with the @ function, thank you for that. I will output the captured error on my test machine and debug it from there. Thanks!

Comment: ps it was very silly of me to not realize the warning was getting returned to my else block of jQuery. Blame it on a worn out mind. I need to pop some 'suppressants'.